# Python argparse with two positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to use python3 argparse to get a CLI like below:

```
python main.py virtual_machine deploy --name "chetan"
python main.py virtual_machine power-on
python main.py image --list
```

I tried something like this, which is not working:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="VM Services")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="Subcommands")

parser.add_argument('virtual_machine', nargs=2, action=TwoPositionalAction, help="Virtual machine operations")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.virtual_machine[1] == "deploy":
    vm_parser = subparsers.add_parser("deploy", help="Virtual machine deploy")
    vm_parser .add_argument("--name", required=False, help="name of the vm")
    vm_parser .set_defaults(func=two_parser_command)
```

Output:

```
python3 main.py virtual_machine deploy
usage: main.py [-h] {} ... virtual_machine virtual_machine
main.py: error: invalid choice: 'virtual_machine' (choose from )
```

Need help on setting 2 or 1 positional parameter(s) with same parser which will call functions to perform respective operation

Comment: What's `TwoPositionalAction`? and `two_parser_command`

Comment: You're right to use a sub-subparser, but it's in the wrong place. `virtual_machine` should be a command, not an argument name.

Comment: besides showing what you want to accept, show what the results should be.

Comment: The `subparser` is itself a `positional`, that takes parser names as `choices`.  Don't try to define other positionals, either for the main parser, or one of the subparsers - at least not until you gets things working with `optionals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="CLI")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="Commands", dest="command")

# Subparser for the 'virtual_machine' command
vm_parser = subparsers.add_parser("virtual_machine", help="Manage virtual machines")
vm_subparsers = vm_parser.add_subparsers(title="Subcommands", dest="vm_command")

# Subcommand for deploying a virtual machine
deploy_parser = vm_subparsers.add_parser("deploy", help="Deploy a virtual machine")
deploy_parser.add_argument("--name", required=True, help="Name of the virtual machine")
deploy_parser.set_defaults(func=deploy_virtual_machine)

# Subcommand for powering on a virtual machine
power_on_parser = vm_subparsers.add_parser("power-on", help="Power on a virtual machine")
power_on_parser.set_defaults(func=power_on_virtual_machine)

# Subparser for the 'image' command
image_parser = subparsers.add_parser("image", help="Manage images")
image_parser.set_defaults(func=list_hypervisor_images)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the nesting is to use [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("VM Services")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="Commands")

# virtual_machine
parser_vm = subparsers.add_parser("virtual_machine")
parser_vm_subparsers = parser_vm.add_subparsers()

# virtual_macine / deploy
parser_vm_deploy = parser_vm_subparsers.add_parser("deploy", help="perform deploy")
parser_vm_deploy.add_argument("--name")

# virtual_machine / power_on
parser_vm_power = parser_vm_subparsers.add_parser("power_on", help="perform power on")

# image
parser_image = subparsers.add_parser("image")
parser_image.add_argument("--list")

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="VM Services")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="Subcommands")

parser.add_argument('virtual_machine', nargs=2, action=TwoPositionalAction, help="Virtual machine operations")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

`subparsers` is a positional, that takes 'cmds' as choices.  But you didn't define any `add_parser` - the `if` stuff after parsing doesn't count.

The error message

main.py: error: invalid choice: 'virtual_machine' (choose from )

shows it's looking for a parser name, but from an empty set of `choices`.

Your second argument with a `virtual_machine` `dest` is a `positional` that expects 2 strings.  But that can only be filled after the `subparser`.  But it wouldn't work even then, once the main parser branches to a subparser, the main doesn't do any more parsing.